# How to select from one dbms_sql.number_table into another

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm passing a list of indices (including duplicates) into a function as a dbms_sql.number_table, and would like to select unique entries from it into another dbms_sql.number_table.

So far I've got something along the lines of this:

```
function selectIndices(tlngIndexList in in dbms_sql.number_table) return number
is
  tlngUniqueIndices dbms_sql.number_table;
begin
  select distinct * from tlngIndexList into tlngUniqueIndices;
  --Etc
```

though SQL Developer is giving me an "ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist" error, so it seems this isn't the right way to do it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `number_table` is an associative (indexed by binary_integer). Presumably you're looking for duplicate values, but if you find any then what index would you expect the result to have? Do they have to be associative arrays or could you use nested tables instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for populating a collection from a SQL query is:

```
select x bulk collect into y from z;
```

The following works in 12.2 (and possibly 12.1 though untested):

```
create or replace function selectIndices
    ( tlngIndexList in dbms_sql.number_table )
    return number
as
    tlngUniqueIndices dbms_sql.number_table;
begin
    select distinct column_value bulk collect into tlngUniqueIndices
    from table(tlngIndexList);

    return tlngUniqueIndices.count;
end selectIndices;
```

In earlier versions you could try using the collection's values as the indices of a second collection as a way of deduplicating it:

```
create or replace function selectIndices
    ( tlngIndexList in dbms_sql.number_table )
    return number
as
    tlngUniqueIndices dbms_sql.number_table;
    i pls_integer := tlngIndexList.first;
begin 
    while i is not null loop
        tlngUniqueIndices(tlngIndexList(i)) := tlngIndexList(i);
        i := tlngIndexList.next(i);
    end loop;

    return tlngUniqueIndices.count;
end selectIndices;
```

Comment: I'm using 11.2, but the latter method seems to work. Thanks!